# Replace value of a Vector in Ruby

Tags: ruby, matrix

I have a Matrix and I want to replace values of a column (or row) by an another single value.

I tried this:

```
m = Matrix.empty(5, 0)
n = Matrix.empty(0, 5)
g = m *n

puts g.column(3).map! { 3 }
```

But `map!` isn't working with **Vector**, and `map` doesn't change values of the column in the Matrix. So how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
g.column(3).class
=> Vector
Vector.instance_methods.grep(/map/)
=> [:map, :map2, :flat_map]
```

Vector haven't `map!` method.

```
 g[0, 0] =3
 NoMethodError: private method `[]=' called for #<Matrix:0x007f8cd8951d18>
```

`[]=` is a private method, you can use `send` method to bypass private:

```
 g.send(:[]=, 0, 0, 3)
 => 3


g = Matrix[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]

5.times do |i|
    g.send(:[]=,i, 3, 3)
end

g
=> Matrix[[0, 0, 0, 3, 0], [0, 0, 0, 3, 0], [0, 0, 0, 3, 0], [0, 0, 0, 3, 0], [0, 0, 0, 3, 0]]

irb(main):580:0> 5.times do |i|
irb(main):581:1* g.send(:[]=, 0, i, 3)
irb(main):582:1> end
=> 5
irb(main):583:0> g
=> Matrix[[3, 3, 3, 3, 3], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Answer (score 1):

The Ruby standard classes for Matrix and Vector don't provide the `map!` method.

One option is for you to write the method yourself, for example by re-opening the class.

A better option (IMHO) is to use a more powerful matrix class.

Take a look at SciRuby: http://sciruby.com/nmatrix/docs/NMatrix.html

The SciRuby package has the NMatrix class which provides this method and many others:

```
[]=(*args)
Modify the contents of an NMatrix in the given cell
```